# CakePHP 3 Passing value depending on which image button is clicked

Tags: html, cakephp

I'm using CakePHP 3. I'm having a form with several elements e.g. text inputs. I would like to additionally add 6 images, one of which should be selected at a time. How can I pass a (hidden) value in a form depending on which image button is clicked (selected). I do not want to make the images the submit buttons. I would like to have them as one of several elements in a form, one on them should always be marked.

Comment: so treat them as radio buttons and check for how to use image in radio button. I suppose that is what you are looking for.

Comment: I made a shortcut in the description, the images are indeed the divs with extra content i.e. images but not only. I am looking for a better solution than radio buttons to solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

I would use Javascript with an onclick event handler on the images div.

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp

On click you could inject a hidden field with e.g. an Image ID in the Form.